# the number of permutations of all the letters of the word STATISTICIAN

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Determine the number of permutations of all the letters of the word STATISTICIAN if the arrangement must begin with C and end in N.

my work:After we fix first letter as S and last letter as N we have 10 letters left

TATISTITIA

Here we have 4 Ts, 2 As ,3 Is, and 1 A.

If all letters were different, the result would have been 10!.

To account for repetitions we need to divide this by (4!*2!*3!).

So, we get 10!/(4!*2!*3!)=12600.

is this the correct way to solve ?

Comment: I think you meant to write $1\, S$ instead of $1\, A$ but it looks good otherwise.

Comment: I did it the second time and got 25,200

Comment: as my answer and im not sure which one is correct, do you mind double checking my work to see if its correct

Comment: I got $12,600$.  Let's do it a (slightly) different way.  You need to choose $4$ slots out of the $10$ to place the $T's$, that's $\binom {10}4$.  Then you need to choose $2$ slots out of the remaining $6$ to place the $A's$, so $\binom {6}2$, and $\binom 43$ for the $I's$.  Thus $\binom {10}4\times \binom 62\times \binom 43=12,600$.

Comment: ok so the answer for sure is 12,600.I was probably over thinking the question when I did it the second time.

Answer (score 1):

If it begins with $C$ and ends with $N$, then the remaining letters are:

STATISTIIA

That is $\{S\cdot 2, T\cdot 3, A\cdot 2, I\cdot 3\}$

So, we are looking for the number of permutations of this multiset, which is:

$$\dfrac{10!}{2!3!2!3!} = 25200$$

Your answer in the comments is correct. Your problem with the first time you did it is that you fixed the S and the N, rather than the C and the N.

Comment: ,i posted a question just a few minutes ago,im not sure if I did it correct or not,do you mind looking at it and seeing if its right ,i would appreciate it.